# Using MikroORM with Jest toMatchObject matcher ends with error: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: __helper

Tags: jestjs, mikro-orm

Sometimes when using MikroORM entities with Jest (TS) in this way:

```
    const ads = await repo.findAll({
        orderBy: {
            providerId: 'asc'
        }
    })

    expect(ads).toMatchObject([
        {
            providerId: 'a',
            title: 'a-changed',
            createdBy: {
                id: firstJobId
            },
            updatedBy: {
                id: secondJobId
            },
            removed: false
        }])
```

it causes this error to be thrown:

> Cannot redefine property: __helper TypeError: Cannot redefine
> property: __helper

When I try to use  `wrap(entity).toPOJO()` a reference to another entity is no longer an object but is converted to an id. In my case the `createdBy` and `updatedBy` becomes a number.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: What version are you on? I believe this should be fixed in the very last versions, as the `__helper` property is now defined as [configurable](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/packages/core/src/entity/EntityHelper.ts#L75).